# MBP Booting from Network

Tags: networking, hard-drive, wireless-networking, boot, nas

I have a Late-2015 MBP running OSX Sierra. I am interested in booting the MBP over a network. There is an overwhelming number of possibilities however none I have seen that would be very easy.

I would like to clone my entire MBP hard drive (all partitions) and use this clone as a target startup disk on the network. Most solutions regarding network booting exist to merely facilitate software installations on a number of computers. My vision is to be able to boot any OS (installed on the distinct partitions of the hard drive) on any computer connected to the network.

The hardware considerations I have made are below:

- Seagate Wireless
- Airport Extreme (or any router w/ external drive)
- Preconfigured Network Attached Storage
- Raspberry Pi
- Xbox One

What I am looking for here is an explanation on which of these would work best. It seems that in the research I have done, the protocols required in booting from the network require hardware that is capable of running an OS to function as a server hence why the first 2 options are not feasible (correct?).

Below is a list of the variety of network booting associations I found in research:

- PXE
- iSCSI
- FOG
- Netboot (Mac)
- FreeNAS

What I am looking for here is the most basic explanation of what distinguishes these from each other and what is recommended. I've gone through so many tutorial guides that I am confused what is being done on the client, what is being done on the server, and if I am still in the realm of what I am trying to do. I am suprised that there is no explicit beginner guide for what I am trying to accomplish either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for using any combination of the above to produce the network boot configuration mentioned? [Although, I would prefer to avoid a preconfigured NAS (a DIY would be an ok option)].

Let me elaborate some on the Xbox:
I recently bought an Xbox One and found a Python 3 framework on the Microsoft Store (MuffinPy). I then discovered that PyPXE provides Pythonic handling of PXE (and likely any of the other that were mentioned in the same category). With the backgrounding of applications on the Xbox One, I dont see why it wouldnt be possible to use my Xbox One as a server for what I wish to accomplish, using an external drive as the target startup disk. This would be an interesting task but seemingly doable.

I appreciate all help and insight in advance!

Comment: There's a decent discussion on Netboot here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88422/netboot-image-where-is-the-user-generated-data-stored/88834#88834 It's not a subject I am too familiar with, but I'm in great doubt that what you want is feasible.

Comment: Is it possible to create a system image from a hard disk that includes all partitions? Then use that image with NetBoot?

Comment: NetBoot is essentially a read-only structure

Comment: I mean that's a start for what I'd like to do

Comment: What you seem to be looking for - essentially your drive structure remoted - would be excruciatingly slow. Remember the days of booting to an OS from CD... imagine it being 1/10 that speed.

Comment: How is that? Because I swear one time I went to Best Buy they had network boot image that they used to boot my computer from and it was decently fast. Also didn't the OS X recovery system use to be web-based, it was decently fast once it got up and running?

Comment: it downloads to the machine & runs from there. It's not a constant 2-way process. That would simply not be practicable. It's also not a full OS, it's a recovery system, far smaller.

Comment: What if that's all it did every time though? Say for instance that I had my MBP "download" and boot the OS of choice from the network storage and used the internal storage of the MBP for file management?